# What font is this please?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

just a simple question: what font is this?
[image]

and where can I find it for free?

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to get you close and take it from there. https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rene-bieder/rbno3-1/extrabold/ is what they suggested.

Finding something free is trickier, but https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator suggested:

https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/jovanny-lemonad/russo-one

Which isnt so bad.